# How to use ssh-agent with Net:OpenSSH Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, ssh-agent

I got three servers, MyServer (centos7), Jumper and DestinationServer. I need to establish SSH connection from MyServer through Jumper to DestinationServer using Perl script with Net:OpenSSH lib.

on the MyServer i have a private rsa key.
on the Jumper and DestinationServer i have a public rsa key to authorize ssh connection.

on the Jumper i can only use the remote command which is an user@servername to connect to the third server.

with Bash it works really fine, i just enable ssh-agent and add rsa key:

```
ssh-agent -s
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh -A user@Jumper user@DestinationServer ls -l
```

which results in remote display of the command

But code in Perl:

```
#!/user/bin/perl
use Net::OpenSSH

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($JumperIP, user =>$user, forward_agent => 1);
$ssh-> capture('user@DestinationServer ls -l');
```

returns same error as Bash code with no agent forwarding (-A):

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from DestinationServerIP port 22:2 Too many authentication failures for user
Disconnected from DestinationServerIP port 22
```

in the documentation (https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH ) it says only

"forward_agent => 1
Note that Net::OpenSSH will not run ssh-agent for you. This has to be done ahead of time and the environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK set pointing to the proper place."

so i got no idea how to attach enabled ssh-agent.

EDIT:
With:

```
BEGIN {
  $Net::OpenSSH::debug_fh = $out;
  $Net::OpenSSH::debug = ~0;
}
```

i get that output:

```
  # open_ex: ['ssh','-V']
# io3 mloop, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 48 at offset 0
#> 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 48 5f 37 2e 34 70 31 2c 20 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 4c 20 31 2e 30 2e 32 6b 2d 66 69 | OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fi
#> 70 73 20 20 32 36 20 4a 61 6e 20 32 30 31 37 0a                                                 | ps  26 Jan 2017.
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 0 at offset 48
# leaving _io3()
# _waitpid(14949) => pid: 14949, rc:
# OpenSSH verion is 7.4p1,
# ctl_path: /home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827, ctl_dir: /home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/
# _is_secure_path(dir: /home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl, file mode: 16832, file uid: 1084, euid: 1084
# _is_secure_path(dir: /home/$USER, file mode: 16872, file uid: 1084, euid: 1084
# set_error(0 - 0)
# call args: ['ssh','-o','ServerAliveInterval=30','-o','ControlPersist=no','-2MNAx','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--']
# file object not yet found at /home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827, state: waiting_for_mux_socket
# tracer attached, ssh pid: 14950, tracer pid: 14951
# file object found at /home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827
# call args: ['ssh','-O','check','-T','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--']
# open_ex: ['ssh','-O','check','-T','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--']
# io3 mloop, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 28 at offset 0
#> 4d 61 73 74 65 72 20 72 75 6e 6e 69 6e 67 20 28 70 69 64 3d 31 34 39 35 30 29 0d 0a             | Master running (pid=14950)..
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 0 at offset 28
# leaving _io3()
# _waitpid(15022) => pid: 15022, rc:
# call args: ['ssh','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--','$USER@DestinationServer ls -l']
# open_ex: ['ssh','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--','$USER@DestinationServer ls -l']
# io3 mloop, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from $DestinationIP port 22:2: Too many authentication failures for $USER
Disconnected from $DestinationIP port 22

# stdout, bytes read: 0 at offset 0
# leaving _io3()
# _waitpid(15023) => pid: 15023, rc:
# DESTROY(Net::OpenSSH=HASH(0x2832240), pid: 14950)
# killing master
# sending exit control to master
# call args: ['ssh','-O','exit','-T','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--']
# open_ex: ['ssh','-O','exit','-T','-S','/home/$USER/.libnet-openssh-perl/$USER-$IP.-14948-620827','-l','$USER','$IP','--']
# io3 mloop, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 20 at offset 0
#> 45 78 69 74 20 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 20 73 65 6e 74 2e 0d 0a                                     | Exit request sent...
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 0 at offset 20
# leaving _io3()
# _waitpid(15025) => pid: 15025, rc:
# _kill_master: 14950
# waitpid(master: 14950) => pid: 14950, rc:
```

I'm not sure, but i do not see -A flag of agent forwarding in that debug or maybe I'm thinking wrong, but I use:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-numbers/agent.28101; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=28102; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 28102;
```

to set ENV by Bash shell before starting Perl script.

Comment: Did you set SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

Comment: yeah, without setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK, connection through Bash doesn't work too.

Comment: [Debug](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#DEBUGGING) could be helpful, `$Net::OpenSSH::debug = ~0;`

Comment: I edited post with debug, but all i see i wrote in edit